# How to download video from dailymotion?

Tags: java, video, html5-video, download

I have to download videos from dailymotion. I searhed for java libraries and apis but I couldn't find anything useful. I learnt selenium at last and tried to use websites for video downloading manually like savefrom etc. Dailymotion videos can't be downloaded from any website right now. Is there a common way to video download form any website. If there is not, can you help me with dailymotion, spesifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Selenium to download videos. It opens savefrom.net in chrome browser, paste a link that is taken from a dailymotion video and just click download button. You can download videos with this way from any website.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Faruk\\IdeaProjects\\Dailymotion\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://en.savefrom.net");

    WebElement textField = driver.findElement(By.id("sf_url"));
    textField.sendKeys("https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x737y37");

    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("sf_submit"));
    button.click();

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download")).click();
```

Comment: Not working. The driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download")) can't find the button.